# How do I add a SwiftUI view to an existing Tab Bar Controller

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an app that uses storyboard, I need one of the tabs to be SwiftUI, how can I add it to my existing project?

Answer (score 1):

I assume someone will need to know this at some point,

step 1.
Add a Hosting View Controller to your storyboard

step 2.
Create a root view controller relationship segue between your navigation controller/tab bar controller and the HostingView Controller

step 3.
create your SwiftUI Class

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnalyticsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
    
}

struct AnalyticsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ("Hello World")
    }
}
```

step 4.
create a UIHostingController class and set the HostingViewController to that class in the class inspector

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class AnalyticsVC: UIHostingController<AnalyticsView> {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder, rootView: AnalyticsView())
    }
}
```

step 5.
build your view controller from your SwiftUI view